# limits of trigonometric series

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, limits-colimits

I'm having some problem with computing (no need to prove, just compute) the limits of some trigonometric series. If you can give tips to compute, it would help me a lot in the future.

1) $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \lfloor(\sqrt n)\rfloor \sin\frac{1}{n} $$
2) $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \sin\frac{\pi n}{2}*\cos\left(\sin \frac{1}{n}\right) $$
3) Let the range of a be (0,$\pi$). Prove that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} ((2\pi n+a)\sin(2\pi n+a)-(2\pi n\sin(2\pi n))= \infty $$

Problems I've had:

The problems I'm having are mostly with the floor limit with the sqrt, and the limits of trigonometric functions. I also tend to miss side limits. Is there a way to make sure after calculating the limits that I did not miss one?

I'd very appreciate if you could also provide me tips or ideas for an efficient way of solving those limits.

(no taylor or l'hopital please)

Comment: Your question's title should be "...trigonometric **sequences**" . There are no series here.

Answer (score 2):

For example: using $\;\lfloor x\rfloor=x-\{x\}\;,\;\;\{x\}:=\;$ the fractional part of $\;x\;$ , we get:

$$\lfloor n\rfloor\sin\frac1n=\left(n-\{n\}\right)\sin\frac1n=\frac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}-\{n\}\sin\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1-0=1$$

Try now the other ones.